# passing variable from beforevalidate to save event

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I need to pass a variable from the `beforeValidate` method in the remote hook to save the event in loopback, how can I do so? I seems `next()` does not take any parameters in the `beforeValidate` method in order to call save.

Here is the sample code

```
Event.beforeRemote('saveEvent', validationHandler);

validationHandler = function (ctx, unused, next){ next()}
Event.saveEvent = function(....)

 Event.remoteMethod(
        'saveEvent',
    {
            description: 'Save event via GET request',
            accepts: paramAccepts,
            returns: paramReturns,
            http: { path: '/:eventName', verb: 'get' }
        }
    );
```

Now here in the validationHandler function, I want to pass a variable in next() so that in the Event.saveEvent function I can retrieve that variable.

Comment: Updated the thread with the code

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks#Remotehooks-Examples

It's possible to display a custom error message and status code with `next` callback.

```
var validationHandler = function (ctx, unused, next){
  var error = new Error('Something Wrong');
  error.statusCode = 400;
  return next(error);
}
```